# slicing a numpy array with characters

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy, sub-array

I have a text file made as:

```
0.01 1 0.1 1 10 100 a
0.02 3 0.2 2 20 200 b
0.03 2 0.3 3 30 300 c
0.04 1 0.4 4 40 400 d
```

I read it as a list `A` and then converted to a numpy array, that is:

```
>>> A
array([['0.01', '1', '0.1', '1', '10', '100', 'a'],
       ['0.02', '3', '0.2', '2', '20', '200', 'b'],
       ['0.03', '2', '0.3', '3', '30', '300', 'c'],
       ['0.04', '1', '0.4', '4', '40', '400', 'd']], 
      dtype='|S4')
```

I just want to extract a sub-array `B`, made of `A` wherever its 4th entry is lower than 30, that should look something like:

```
B = array([['0.01', '1', '0.1', '1', '10', '100', 'a'],
           ['0.02', '3', '0.2', '2', '20', '200', 'b']])
```

When dealing with arrays, I usually do simply `B = A[A[:,4]<30]`, but in this case (maybe due to the presence of characters/strings I've never worked with) it doesn't work, giving me this:

```
>>> A[A[:,4]<30]
array(['0.01', '1', '0.1', '1', '10', '100', 'a'], 
      dtype='|S4')
```

and I can't figure out the reason. I'm not dealing with a code of mine and I don't think I can switch all this to structures or dictionaries: any suggestion for doing this with numpy arrays? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You have to compare `int` to `int`

```
A[A[:,4].astype(int)<30]
```

or `str` to `str`

```
A[A[:,4]<'30']
```

However, notice that the latter would work in your *specific example*, but won't work generally because you are comparing `str` ordering (for example, `'110' < '30'` returns `True`, but `110 < 30` returns `False`)

---

`numpy` will infer your elements' types from your data. In this case, it attributed the `type = '|S4'` to your elements, meaning they strings of length 4. This is probably a consequence of the underlying `C` code (which enhances `numpy`'s performance) that requires elements to have fixed types.

To illustrate this difference, check the following code:

```
>>> np.array([['0.01', '1', '0.1', '1', '10', '100', 'a']])
array(['0.01', '1', '0.1', '1', '10', '100', 'a'], dtype='|S4')
```

The inferred type of strings of length 4, which is the max length of your elements (in elem `0.01`). Now, if you expclitily define it to hold general type objects, it will do what you want

```
>>> np.array([[0.01, 1, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 'a']], dtype=object)
array([0.01, 1, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 'a'], dtype=object)
```

and your code `A[A[:,4]<30]` would work properly.

For more information, ***[this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.dtypes.html)*** is a very complete guide

Comment: But when I deal with the file, I read them as integer and float, why do they become strings when I pass to a numpy array?

Comment: It converts to `str` because your arrays have elements with different type s. `NumPy` tries to infer which are the types of your elements

Comment: Omg, I didn't notice that my array was made of strings! When I read the file I create a list of lists and I read each entry as integer, float, or string. I don't get why numpy changes them all to strings...

Answer (score 1):

```
In [86]: txt='''0.01 1 0.1 1 10 100 a
    ...: 0.02 3 0.2 2 20 200 b
    ...: 0.03 2 0.3 3 30 300 c
    ...: 0.04 1 0.4 4 40 400 d'''
In [87]: A = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), dtype=str)
In [88]: A
Out[88]: 
array([['0.01', '1', '0.1', '1', '10', '100', 'a'],
       ['0.02', '3', '0.2', '2', '20', '200', 'b'],
       ['0.03', '2', '0.3', '3', '30', '300', 'c'],
       ['0.04', '1', '0.4', '4', '40', '400', 'd']], dtype='<U4')
In [89]: A[:,4]
Out[89]: array(['10', '20', '30', '40'], dtype='<U4')
```

`genfromtxt`, as a default tries to make floats.  But in that case the character column would be `nan`.  Instead I specified `str` dtype.

So a numeric test would require converting the column to numbers:

```
In [90]: A[:,4].astype(int)
Out[90]: array([10, 20, 30, 40])
In [91]: A[:,4].astype(int)<30
Out[91]: array([ True,  True, False, False])
```

In this case a string comparison also works:

```
In [99]: A[:,4]<'30'
Out[99]: array([ True,  True, False, False])
```

Or if we use dtype=None, it infers dtype by column and makes a structured array:

```
In [93]: A1 = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), dtype=None,encoding=None)
In [94]: A1
Out[94]: 
array([(0.01, 1, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 'a'), (0.02, 3, 0.2, 2, 20, 200, 'b'),
       (0.03, 2, 0.3, 3, 30, 300, 'c'), (0.04, 1, 0.4, 4, 40, 400, 'd')],
      dtype=[('f0', '<f8'), ('f1', '<i8'), ('f2', '<f8'), ('f3', '<i8'), ('f4', '<i8'), ('f5', '<i8'), ('f6', '<U1')])
```

Now we can select a field by name, and test it:

```
In [95]: A1['f4']
Out[95]: array([10, 20, 30, 40])
```

Either way we can select rows based on the True/False mask or the corresponding row indices:

```
In [96]: A[[0,1],:]
Out[96]: 
array([['0.01', '1', '0.1', '1', '10', '100', 'a'],
       ['0.02', '3', '0.2', '2', '20', '200', 'b']], dtype='<U4')

In [98]: A1[[0,1]]     # A1 is 1d
Out[98]: 
array([(0.01, 1, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 'a'), (0.02, 3, 0.2, 2, 20, 200, 'b')],
      dtype=[('f0', '<f8'), ('f1', '<i8'), ('f2', '<f8'), ('f3', '<i8'), ('f4', '<i8'), ('f5', '<i8'), ('f6', '<U1')])
```